# Unity Player velocity.y changes when running horizontally over a composite collider 2D?

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I have a tile map, with tiles. I added a tile `Collider 2D` and a `Composite Collider 2D` to the tile map. Everything was working perfectly, until i noticed i couldn't jump. My jump code is based on the player `velocity.y <= 0`, and moving horizontally on the composite collider changes the player velocity.y, even though moving on a box collider would not. I am very confused. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: screenshot of the editor showing the <code>velocity.y</code>]

In the picture the player is only running horizontally, no code is changing the `velocity.y`, and the `player`'s `velocity.y` shouldn't be at `1.19` and should be at 0

Comment: Please make your Inpsector bigger/wider if possible .... I'm pretty sure it says something like `1.19203... e-8` or something like that, indicating that the value is extremely close to `0` and probably caused by some `float` imprecision ;)

Comment: @derHugo holy crap i had no idea something like that can even exist! Thank you so much!